# Create table with foreach without repeating table headings

Tags: php, arrays, printing, foreach, echo

I want to create a html table dynamically with php and include data from two arrays.

However, the code I have written repeats the table headings for each row (pun  not intented).

How can I create a table that only has the table heading tags at the top?

Here is my code:

```
    foreach (array_combine($even, $odd) as $products => $numbers) {

    echo "<table border='1'>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Product name</th>";
    echo "<th>Sold</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    print("<td>" . ($products) . "</td>");
    print("<td>" . ($numbers) . "</td>");
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the table header out of your foreach look:

```
    echo "<table border='1'>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Product name</th>";
    echo "<th>Sold</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    foreach (array_combine($even, $odd) as $products => $numbers) {

     echo "<tr>";
     print("<td>" . ($products) . "</td>");
     print("<td>" . ($numbers) . "</td>");
     echo "</tr>";

    }

    echo "</table>";
```